# What conditions must a transformation matrix $A$ satisfy if it preserves the length of some non-zero vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Real square transformation matrices that preserve some real non-zero vectors' *directions* must have at least one real eigenvalue. What about real square matrices that preserve *length* for some real non-zero vectors/do not preserve length for any real non-zero vectors?

In other words, how to find all real $n\times n$ matrices that satisfy $v^Tv = v^TA^TAv$ for some non-zero vectors $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: No, he said *some*

Comment: For what it's worth: $v^TA^TAv-v^Tv =v^T(A^TA-I)v.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: as every (real or complex) matrix $M$ can be decomposed as $M=UP$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $P:=\sqrt{M^\top M}$ positive semi-definite, the question reduces to study the singular values of $M$ (that is, the eigenvalues of $P$) and see how they are related to the existence or non-existence of such non-zero vector.